# JNBridge JMS Asynchronous batch failed, anyone know?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have seen on our BT 2013 Environment's event logs a lot of warnings like below

> "The adapter "JNBridge JMS" raised an error message. Details "Asynchronous Batch Failed. HRESULT: C0C0162F" . "

This adapter is used to receive messages from AMQ.  Have you guys encountered this error? what was the cause? and what was the impact? I have found nothing on google searching for the issue.

Comment: Has anything at all changed on the queue server?  The team at JNBridge has always been super responsive.  Don't hesitate to contact them if this is a critical situation.

Comment: Not that I know of, this error seems a one of have not seen it reoccured. This is possibly due to that while this adapter was in process the host instances was restarted but I am not sure.